# update-aide.conf command not found

Tags: ids, aide

I'm trying to setup **aide** IDS on my ubuntu server, I followed the official installation guide but when I try to use the command "**update-aide.conf**" to generate new config I get error

```
$ update-aide.conf: command not found
```

I tried to search for the file in the system using **find** but found nothing:

```
$ sudo find / -name "update-aide.conf"
$
```

I tried to reinstalled aide again multiple times and the same error happen.

**System**:
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server - 1GB Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v0.17 `aide` supports the inclusion of directories and executable configuration files (see `@@x_include` macro in `man 5 aide.conf`). This is why `update-aide.conf` is no longer needed and provided. You can simply call `aide` directly and it will generate the configuration on the fly.

See also `/usr/share/doc/aide/NEWS.Debian.gz` for more details:

```
aide (0.17-1) unstable; urgency=medium

    [...]
    Most of the functionality of update-aide.conf and the aide.wrapper
    has moved into aide proper. The two scripts have been removed. This also
    means that the @@{ROOTPREFIX} prefix is no longer added to every rule
    written in the configuration. If you have been using this feature, please
    consider one of these alternatives:
    - the root_prefix configuration option allows you to specify a single
      prefix
    - write your own tool that, for example, copies the contents of
      /etc/aide/aide.conf.d to /etc/aide/aide.conf.container.d and does the
      appropriate preprocessing of the copied rules.
    - write/generate your own per-container ruleset in a different directory
      and @@x_include it appropriately.
    [...]

 -- Marc Haber <mh+debian-packages@zugschlus.de>  Sun, 17 Jan 2021 16:29:27 +0100
```

Comment: Thank you. How to run aide to generate the config? I tried running [ sudo aide ] but I get error [ missing configuration ] and I have to explicitly specify the config file location manually like [ sudo aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf ]. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Running `aide ---config /etc/aide/aide.conf --init` as root should be sufficient to initialize the database (`aide.conf` is part of the `aide-common` package)